# Save imported oracle db dmp in docker image

Tags: oracle, docker

I am using a docker image to start and run the Oracle db via docker-compose file.  I have also created a dmp file of my application and been able to import it to the oracle server on docker using the `docker exec -it` command.

However every time I restart the docker container, the data is lost and I need to do the entire process of importing the dmp file again by doing a bash on the Oracle server in the docker container.

Is there any way I can save that data to the Oracle db server running on the docker container? I have tried docker commit however that did not work.

Do I need to use the `volume` bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that volumes will be needed.  Here's a full  example working in my setup.

My volume mapping is :  `-v /Users/klrice/workspace/dockerdb/data:/opt/oracle/oradata`

Then oracle directory : `DIRECTORY docker_vol AS '/opt/oracle/oradata';`

expdp cmd from host : `docker exec  -it   db_193 expdp klrice/klrice@xe tables=t1 directory=docker_vol dumpfile=klrice.dmp logfile=klrice_exp.log`

Resulting files are in the host mapped location: `/Users/klrice/workspace/dockerdb/data`

```
docker run --name db_193 --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined \
-p 1521:1521  \
-p 8000:8000  \
-e ORACLE_SID=orcl \
-e ORACLE_PDB=xe \
-e ORACLE_PWD=oracle \
-e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=UTF8 \
-v /Users/klrice/workspace/dockerdb/data:/opt/oracle/oradata \
oracle/database:19.3.0-ee

kriss-MacBook-Pro:dockerdb klrice$ sql system/oracle@//localhost:1521/xe

SQLcl: Release 19.4 Production on Mon Nov 11 11:44:47 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Mon Nov 11 2019 11:44:48 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0


SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY docker_vol AS '/opt/oracle/oradata';

Directory DOCKER_VOL created.

SQL> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY docker_vol TO klrice;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
kriss-MacBook-Pro:dockerdb klrice$  docker exec  -it   db_193 expdp klrice/klrice@xe tables=t1 directory=docker_vol dumpfile=klrice.dmp logfile=klrice_exp.log

Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Nov 11 16:45:01 2019
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Starting "KLRICE"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  klrice/********@xe tables=t1 directory=docker_vol dumpfile=klrice.dmp logfile=klrice_exp.log
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/MARKER
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
. . exported "KLRICE"."T1"                               6.680 MB 1000000 rows
Master table "KLRICE"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for KLRICE.SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01 is:
  /opt/oracle/oradata/klrice.dmp
Job "KLRICE"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at Mon Nov 11 16:45:15 2019 elapsed 0 00:00:13



kriss-MacBook-Pro:dockerdb klrice$ ls /Users/klrice/workspace/dockerdb/data/klrice*
/Users/klrice/workspace/dockerdb/data/klrice.dmp    /Users/klrice/workspace/dockerdb/data/klrice_exp.log
```